# How do I create a chromeless window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, silverlight

We used to be able to use javascript in IE to produce a chromeless window...no buttons, scrollbars or even the standard edges of the browser window.

My question: Is there any way to accomplish this type of window look from the web with today's browsers?

Comment: How does this relate to Silverlight?

Comment: Becuase if this can be done with silverlight then I would use silverlight.

Comment: by that logic, you could tag it `peanut-butter-bandsaw` as well, since you might use those if you could.

Comment: @Bears will eat you - not really...if you could write an application in PBSharp you may be right, but I originally tagged it as silverlight for a reason.  I had a hunch that it may be possible with silverlight, because with silverlight you can create standalone applications. However, I am not very familiar with how the silverlight standalone apps work. So…if I could use a silverlight standalone app to some how achieve the UI behavior I want and some one with interest in silverlight knows whether or not this could be done in silverlight I would like to know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Chromeless windows are possible with OOB (out of browswer) silverlight apps in Silverlight 4. Below is a link a with a video with code and a video demonstrating how it looks and works.**

http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2010/03/15/Chromeless-Window-for-OOB-applications-in-Silverlight-40-RC.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Nope, and because it was abandoned for security reasons (exploit example from 2004 [here](http://www.windowssecrets.com/comp/040506)), it's not likely to come back. Sadly.

Related:

- [Mozilla Prism](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism), a framework to run chromeless web apps (without the browser controls)
- [Kiosk mode in IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780)
- [Kiosk mode in Opera](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/)
- [Secure Kiosk Plugin for FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/509/)

(all of these require setting up on the client's machine)

Comment: That really sucks.  How does window chrome compromise security?

Comment: @pierre see the link from 2004 I added.

Comment: @Pirreten It makes a web application look like a native application to the user. Think the pages with 'click to scan your registry' GIFs in them which look like Windows windows, but worse.pages

Comment: @Pierreten I disagree. With a chromeless window, it's possible to emulate the look and feel of the guest OS down to the last pixel - in IE, IIRC, even with a customizable task bar icon. Stuff good enough to even fool a programmer, let alone an ordinary user.

Answer (score 1):

mozilla just announced...  http://github.com/mozilla/chromeless