# Chrome: remove window border / decoration

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible somehow via a Chrome extension to remove most of the window border content (like address bar, tab bar)?

I'd like to have some standalone windows with some webpages inside but without any space wasted.

My purpose is for example to build a Chrome extension which strips everything out from the site except the Flash/video/whateverobject and scales that to the full size of the window. So I get a Chrome window with just the video inside and no space wasted on anything else (like address bar or tab bar or whatever). Similar as for example the VLC player window.

I searched a bit around but found nothing a like. Although I can remember that I have heard of something similar which Google called standalone web applications or so: Where you could create links on your desktop to web applications which just look like desktop applications because they don't have the address bar. But I cannot find this feature (or how to do this with my Chrome).

Comment: Related (but not Chrome related): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026075/how-do-i-create-a-chromeless-window

Comment: How to create those links: click on the page icon on the top right, then the first entry of the menu...

Comment: @Lucero: What menu entry exactly? I'm not sure if I have that here. My menu entries when I rightclick on the tab are: New tab, reload tab, duplicate, anchor, close, close other, close right tabs, open previously closed tab, save all tabs as bookmarks.

Comment: @Albert, not a right-click on a tab, the "page" menu on the top right of the window!

Comment: @Lucero: What menu exactly? You mean where I have new-tab, new-window, new-incognito-window, cut-out, copy, paste, ...? And how is the option called?

Comment: @Albert, the one with Cut/Copy/Paste. Option is called "Create application shortcuts..."

Comment: @Albert, I made a screenshot for you: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/36793ecf7c.png

Comment: @Lucero: I don't have that option here in that menu. I have version 6.0.447.0 dev (Mac build). Is that version too new / old? Or is that feature not available on Mac? Or is it in some other menu? (But I cannot remember that I ever have seen it anywhere.)

Comment: Ah, it really seems that this feature is only Win/Linux at the moment. Whereby it seems that they have already implemented it (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13148) -- strange that this is not in the dev build yet. But not sure if that is anyway helpful. What I want is to convert one existing tab to such a window (via some extension).

Comment: @Albert, since this was there since the very first release of the Win Chrome I wasn't aware that this was not present in the Mac version. That said, I don't know how to enable this feature through JS, and especially not on the Mac version... (that's why I only posted a comment here and not an answer) ;)

Comment: Thanks anyway -- now I know for sure that I just have not overlooked it but that App-mode is just not available on Mac yet.

Comment: @Albert, I've made an extension that does exactly this, http://www.qtax.se/resizetomedia :-) Will update it soon with some more useful features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you can get with an extension is a window with a type `popup`.

Using [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create):

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "https://example.com", type: "popup"})
```

This will get rid of every window decoration except system title bar/borders.

---

A Chrome App can, potentially, go [further](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps#look). You can [create a window](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create) without system borders:

```
chrome.app.window.create({
  url: "page.html",
  frame: { type: "none" },
  innerBounds: { /* position and size */}
});
```

Note that you will have to implement things like [draggable areas](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-FrameOptions) and a way to close the window yourself.

Comment: How would you transform an existing window to remove its frame or window decoration? *Edit:* Ah, I guess via `chrome.windows.update`.

Comment: @Albert You can't. You can create a new popup window passing the tab ID you want to move there.

Comment: I try to use this but I get `Cannot read property 'create' of undefined(…)`

Comment: @HugoNakamura Sounds like you're trying to do that from a content script; that won't work, you need to message your background page to do it for you.

Comment: I was trying to use this command from console. I wanted to open a url in a new page with no frame. Isn't it possible to use `chrome.windows` from console?

Comment: @HugoNakamura Normal webpages do not have any access to _extension_ API. That goes for the console as well.

Comment: @Xan Oh I see. If I wanted to do that then I would have to create an chrome app to open that specific `url` with that specific properties then?

Comment: You could, using `<webview>`, but that's not the purpose of Chrome Apps.

Answer (score 8):

typing this in your console opens the current page in a new window, without the bookmark or the tab bars:

```
javascript:window.open(location.href, "detab", "toolbar=0"); window.close()
```

You can have your extension do the same.

Comment: If you put this on a bookmark you will get a bookmarklet that you can click whenever you want to make the current window 'super minimal'. Example here https://i.imgur.com/qGhz77I.png Works on Chrome / Firefox

Answer (score 0):

How about plain, old `open(location, '_blank', 'fullscreen')` (as in `window.open`)?

Answer (score 0):

in manifest.json write example:

```
"app":{ 
    "urls":["http://www.google.com"],
    "launch":{
        "web_url":"https://www.google.com/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Note: this describes a [hosted app](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide)

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + f11 removes chrome window decorations, bookmark bar search bar etc.