# Window.open with Parameters Options not working

Tags: javascript

I am using window.open as shown below

```
window.open("<%=forHyperLink%>",'name_' + Math.random(),'height=600,width=800,resizable=0');
```

But i dont want to have Title Window and URL address Bar not to visible and also the Borders not to be visible .

Please help me , as how to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a chromeless window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026075/how-do-i-create-a-chromeless-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i dont want to have Title Window and URL address Bar not to visible and also the Borders not to be visible

This is no longer possible in modern browsers for security reasons. See this question: [How do I create a chromeless window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026075/how-do-i-create-a-chromeless-window)

Comment: Thank you Pekka very much , then any alternate approach as how to achive this ??

Comment: @user sorry, in the context of a web site, this is no longer possible. You would have the user to install something locally like [Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/)