# How to manipulate cross-browser windows via javascript addon/extension hiding address bar, menu bar, etc?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a `cross-browser` `MVC` web app with a `javascript` browser `extension` that uses a background script, is it possible to hide the address bar/navigation, the browser window menus, side bar and other toolbars?

The only thing I really want to keep is the tabs, though I would like to hide the add tab button as well.

This web app will run by itself a browser window, I have already got the extension doing that, so it won't affect other website functionality.

Question: Is this possible, if so, how and what api's should I focus on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to hide a browser's UI:

1) In any environment, you can popup a 'chomeless window' popup, which is discussed here: [How do I create a chromeless window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026075/how-do-i-create-a-chromeless-window)

2) In a mobile environment, primarily Android, you can develop a Progressive Web App which will be able to open the mobile browser without the UI. See: [Create a PWA in under 5 min's](https://medium.com/dev-channel/learn-how-to-build-a-pwa-in-under-5-minutes-c860ad406ed)

Given your use case, it sounds like option 1 is your best bet, but likely it won't satisfy all your requirements.

Comment: Ok thinking through alternatives, you can perform browser.window.create() and generate a panel, detached panel or popup. Basically gives you a window without anything on it, address bar, menu bar, tool bars and tabs, they're all gone. Maybe it is possible to add just the tabs to this?

Comment: And yes aiming for desktop browsers

Comment: @Hank I haven't seen an example with just tabs in my travels. That'd be interesting, though, comment back if you find something.